# Generic to check if parameter types of object are equal

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write an update function that takes a target object `a` and it needs to update the key `aKey` with the value of another object `b`, with its own key `bKey`.

I tried using this code:

```js
const updateValue = <T1, T1Key extends keyof T1, T2, T2Key extends keyof T2>(
  a: T1,
  aKey: T1Key,
  b: T2,
  bKey: T2Key
) => {
  a[aKey] = b[bKey];
  // This gives error
  // 'T1' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T2'.ts(2322)
};

const a = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'b',
};

const b = {
  c: 2,
  d: 'd',
};
```

This is correct behaviour:

```
updateValue(a, 'a', b, 'c');
```

This is correct because `a` on object `a` exists, and is of type `number`, same as the key `c` in object `b`, which is also a `number`.

What should not work:

```
updateValue(a, 'b', b, 'c');
```

Here the type of key `b` in object `a` is of type `string`, while key `c` in object `b` is of type `number`, this should not be allowed, with above code it works because it only check if both keys exist.

Is there a way to type check this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change the constraints a bit. Both `T1` and `T2` should be `Records` of some kind where `K1` and `K2` are a key they respectively have.

We can now say that `T1` is a `Record<K1, any>`, because we don't care what the type of the value is here. But for `T2`, we constrain it to be a `Record<K2, T1[K]>`. So for the property `K2` it should have the same type as `T1` has for property `K1`

```
const updateValue = <
  T1 extends Record<K1, any>, 
  T2 extends Record<K2, T1[K1]>, 
  K1 extends string, 
  K2 extends string
>(
  a: T1,
  aKey: K1,
  b: T2,
  bKey: K2
) => {
  a[aKey] = b[bKey] as any;
};
```

We also have to supress the assignment error by using a type assertion.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&target=99&jsx=0&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgBwCYEMoFMBqKA2d0wC8MAPALABQMMAKgIwzoAeGYSEMASuqAE5IkA0nQA0MFGACeAPjGVqNAEyMW6Nh258BgxWPoBtYQF1ZMeTGErW7GNF4BLMAHM5VC8ubWOdx08rSACnMUAC5aUWDBdEkw4RFzACMwpXi3BKiY90oASiJpGABvYP0UDKMiGAT9dOjylA4JSQBuSgBfFopKUEhYFAqit1CYCLSwgHIEsdT2yi7waEr%2082Aw3XMkcaQpto7ZikRUDGw8dACUMTGUKcqL4DHsjoO0LFx8M4vJsQTb%206agA)